# ImportError using matplotlib TKinter Backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, backend, importerror

I'm developing a user interface in python using the `Tkinter` interface and the matplotlib TkAgg backend for drawing graphs on a Linux machine. A week ago, I had a working code, but then some system reboot/update was issued.

Now I'm facing an issue importing matplotlib together with its TkAgg backend. This is a very reduced version of the official Tkinter [embedding example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) from the matplotlib page (the example itself does not work, either, crashing with the same ImportError):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,3,5])
plt.show()
```

I run this script from the console and get the following output:

```
<58> python matplotlibtkinter.py --verbose-helpful
$HOME=/home/optimi/bzfhende
matplotlib data path /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data
loaded rc file /home/optimi/bzfhende/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc
matplotlib version 1.3.1
verbose.level helpful
interactive is False
platform is linux2
CACHEDIR=/home/optimi/bzfhende/.matplotlib
Using fontManager instance from /home/optimi/bzfhende/.matplotlib/fontList.cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "matplotlibtkinter.py", line 3, in <module>
       import matplotlib.pylab as plt
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 269, in <module>
       from matplotlib.pyplot import *
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 98, in <module>
_      backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 28, in pylab_setup
       globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 14, in <module>
       import matplotlib.backends.windowing as windowing
ImportError: No module named windowing
```

I asked our admin to update the system-wide matplotlib installation, but this did not resolve the issue.
Googling troubles with the windowing backend does not show any direct hit. 
It must have something to do with the installed packages, but I am still reluctant to set up an individual installation : If the system-wide configuration is not repaired, other people in my group checking out the tool will end up posting the same question here.

I appreciate every help you can give me on reparing this.

EDIT: Maybe I should mention that, no matter what backend I choose, I do not see plots anymore.

EDIT2: Thanks to user tcaswell, I figured that the reason for the Error is the simplest reason one can imagine: windowing.{py|pyc} is missing in the matplotlib/backends directory. For rebuilding matplotlib, I checked out the latest version from git as mentioned in the [matplotlib-faq](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#source-install-from-git). From the matplotlib-repo, running

```
python setup.py build
```

reveals that the tk-dev libraries/headers are missing for rebuilding the tkagg-backend

LAST EDIT: After having the tk-dev package at hand, I was able to locally build and
install matplotlib inside a virtual environment. This was the trick.

Comment: can you import `matplotlib.pyplot` from a python/ipython terminal?

Comment: Dear Francesco, this depends on the matplotlibrc configuration. With a default ('Agg') backend, the import works, but no plot is drawn when using plt.show() as in the above example. Changing the backend to "TkAgg" in the matplotlibrc-file and reopening a python command prompt terminates the import with the error shown above.

Comment: It's normal that you don't see anything with `Agg`, it's not interactive. Make sure that Tkagg is installed. On linux (and some Unix), a simple way is to try building matplotlib from source. If you issue `python setup.py build` the first part checks what dependences and backends are installed. For instance in my kubuntu matplotlib from the package manager comes with tkagg build in, but it is not actually installed in the system, so I can't use it if I build matplotlib myself (unless I install it)

Comment: `backends.windowing` is a bit of MS windows helper code for the tk backend.  It is imported by `tkagg` and ends up providing no-op functions if you are not on windows. It looks like your matplotlib installation is borked and you are missing the file.  Can you check if `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/windowing.py` exists?

Comment: @tcaswell: No, the windowing.py is missing the backends/-directory, but the Tkagg.py is there.

Comment: And indeed, on my Windows-machine, I have windowing.py in the backends. I mean, this resolves the issue, right? I guess the cleanest way is a clean reinstallation of matplotlib. For testing, I will try to set up a virtual environment on the Linux machine tomorrow, to see if a clean reinstallationof matplotlib works well with the rest of our distribution.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano: When editing my original question, I saw that rebuilding matplotlib from source was exactly your suggestion. Thank you